# How to setup git permissions to repositories

Tags: git, github

How can I setup git server, than different users (clients, not the server users) can access different repositories? I want the behavior, like it is on the github, where you always access the "git" user on their server (git@github.com) but you can modify only some of the repositories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this kind of behavior with gitolite.
http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html

> Gitolite allows you to setup git hosting on a central server, with fine-grained access control and many more powerful features.

Comment: Yepp, as long as you only want/need a Git remote then Gitolite is awesome. It's flexible, robust, hardly uses any resources at all, and requires very little maintenance.